# InnoDB performance

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I know there are plenty of information on this topic, but I think I've tried everything I can, and don't know any new ideas (if any?) about increasing my MySQL database performance.

Situation: I use eTesting platform (taotesting if anybody knows it). It uses MySQL database, with 8 tables. At this moment one of those tables has ~500k rows. Others are either empty or has ~10-15 rows. At first mysql performance was terrible using this platform, then I decided to convert MyISAM tables to InnoDB and make some my.cnf changes. This seemed to have improved performance, but not as much as I wanted.

Server has 1 CPU / 4 cores. 6 GB RAM. It's not dedicated to MySQL, it also hosts PHP/apache/nginx.

What's more, there are about 80% more selects from database then inserts/updates/deletes.

Any ideas how to further (if possible) improve mysql configuration are welcome .

Here's my.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 32M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 50
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 200
#table_cache            = 1M
sort_buffer_size       = 1M
read_buffer_size       = 1M
join_buffer_size    = 1M
#thread_concurrency     = 8
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
tmp_table_size = 64M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 2M
query_cache_size        = 2M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log = /var/log/mysql/testing_req_nec.log
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size     = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
#open_files_limit = 8192
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

EDIT:

Ok, I thought actual numbers were not needed since I said that performance I got wasn't enough for me. I'm using Jmeter to do performance testing. One example would be: Student can login, select test,  submit his answers, and end test. I've tried doing this with ~30 students, and here's what I got:

- Login: ~2 seconds (best case scenario), 8s (worst case)
- Select test: ~5s - 7s (best case), ~20s - 25s worst case.
- Submit answers to question: ~5 - 7s (best case), ~30s worst case.
- Test ending, same as other submits.

See now I would like to have best case scenario for more students (more threads). Problem is that this eTesting platform doesn't use tradidional relational DB model (it uses RDF triples if you've heard) and stores them into MySQL tables. There are a lot of queries, one submit ~80 queries. Sof if test has ~15 items, 1 student sends ~2k queries.

And I've tried EXPLAIN. Can't really help since I can't change eTesting platform source code without breaking everything else, nor can I change table structure (besides changing it's engine, maybe some indexes?)

EDIT: 
submit queries example:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3d10

tables structure:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3d11

```
mysql> show variables LIKE '%buffer_pool%';
+------------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name                | Value      |
+------------------------------+------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 8          |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size      | 4294967296 |
+------------------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Explain on one of more complex queries:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) as count FROM statements WHERE (predicate = 'http://www.tao.lu/Ontologies/TAODelivery.rdf#DeliveryExecutionDelivery' AND (object = 'https://etestas.nec.lt/tao_ssl_dev.rdf#i139266227459751316')) AND subject IN (SELECT subject FROM statements WHERE (predicate = 'http://www.tao.lu/Ontologies/TAODelivery.rdf#DeliveryExecutionSubject' AND (object = 'https://etestas.nec.lt/tao_ssl_dev.rdf#i1392637693114892'))) AND subject IN (SELECT subject FROM statements WHERE predicate = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type' AND object in ('http://www.tao.lu/Ontologies/TAODelivery.rdf#DeliveryExecution'));
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type           | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | statements | ref            | k_po          | k_po | 990     | const,const |    1 | Using where |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | statements | index_subquery | k_sp,k_po     | k_sp | 990     | func,const  |    1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | statements | index_subquery | k_sp,k_po     | k_sp | 990     | func,const  |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Profile the queries, post the actual numbers instead of "terrible performance", that means nothing. Use `EXPLAIN` to see what your queries are doing, and of course, design your tables so they can exploit performance that InnoDB can offer.

Comment: See my edit for more info.

Comment: You can turn on slow query logging, stress-test your app with Jmeter again and once it's done - pull the queries from the log, profile them with EXPLAIN and post the results here. Those numbers are way too big for a setup such as yours, you've increased buffer pool (I hope you restarted MySQL server after that, if you haven't - run `SELECT variables LIKE '%buffer_pool%'` to see what MySQL is actually allocating). Settings seem fine, question is what's happening behind the scenes there, 500k rows is not that much really.

Comment: Oh trust me, I've restarted MySQL. I've been working with these configs for a while now, not just few days work. And about slow queries, there seem to be no queries that takes longer then 1 sec, at least according to MySQL Tuner/tuning primer. And as you can see, slow queries log is turned on. It might that I can't increase performance any more, maybe this is all that eTesting application can do.

Comment: It might be that it's not MySQL's fault at all, if there are tunnels infront of it and apps written in some scripting language then it might be that their response time is hurting the performance. However, SELECT queries are usually lightning-fast with InnoDB (given the fact your tables are properly constructed, with appropriate indexing in place).

Comment: Just to give you an idea of what I'm talking about, I added one submit queries example, and tables structures. see my edit.

Comment: Yes, everything looks fine, although I'd personally index the hash of the URI rather than URI itself - index would always be of a fixed size. What might have happened is that the InnoDB settings didn't take on. What happens when you run this query: `SELECT variables LIKE '%buffer_pool%'` - what's the value in there?

Comment: All innodb settings are set ^^ I've checked this a lot while configuring. see my edit. EDIT: you said innodb selects are lightning fast, that may be so, but when there are so many of them? That might be causing problems, and there's not really much more I can do.

Comment: Since data comes from buffer pool (in memory), then that part must be extremely fast, **if** the buffer pool is indeed able to store entire working data set. That's why I suggested to really confirm whether that setting took place. Also, queries them selves should be profiled, using MySQL terminal preferably (or if you have GUI tool like SQLYog) so you avoid any possible bottlenecks. Without actually running the EXPLAIN on those queries you posted, it'll be impossible to determine if it's really MySQL causing such a huge load time or not.

Comment: There isn't enough hard facts to help here, your stabbing in the dark. Your diagnosis ability is only as good as the diagnostic data you collect. @N.B. suggest turning on slow query log, I second that, and capture everything. Then us a tool like pt-query-digest to get an idea of what your server is doing.

Comment: This was solved by seperating dynamic and static data. Static data - MySQL, dynamic data (tables that keep increasing, like student results) - Redis. Problem was not with MySQL configuration, but with eTesting platform architecture itself. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Halo @CrazySabbath, i know this is 7 years old question. would you share Jmeter conf for performance testing of taoPlatform. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can check [MySQL Tuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) and [Tuning Primer](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer), both scripts can help you optimize your server configuration

Answer (score 0):

The `InnoDB` performance measures varies according to Hardware,OS and also various factors.You can check out this for the detailed [InnoDB Performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/)